# Change the shape by adding image channel

Tags: python, numpy

My x_train.shape is `[50, 12, 6]`, then I've try to change into `[50,12, 6, 3]`. A '3' is for use image channel.

The numpy `expand_dim(np.expand_dim(x_train, axis=3)` is just changed into `[50,12,6,1]`.

How do I change my x_train.shape into desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.repeat()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html)

```
a = a[..., None] # equivalent to np.expand_dims(a, axis=3)
a = a.repeat(repeats=3, axis=3)
print a.shape
# (50, 12, 6, 3)
```